# What causes my inverter MOSFET to produce this incorrect output?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, layout

I'm new to layout. I followed a couple of tutorial on youtube to create an inverter using Magic VLSI, despite following step by step I cannot obtain the same output. I'm using scmos library.

Is there something obviously wrong?

[image]

Comment: `I cannot obtain the same output` - it's an inverter so it'll not be the same.

Comment: Yes bottom metal and top one are respectively labelled as gnd! and vdd! @jp314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the testbench code. I was using

```
Vin in gnd pulse(0V 1.8V 0NS 1NS 1NS 20NS 50NS)
.tran 5NS 200NS
```

Seems using "NS" or ns" was the mistake. When removed the tool produced the expected output.

I am using magic 8.2 r157.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the output is in phase with the input (not inverted as it should be). Also it is centered around VDD with some R.C decays.

It appears that your ground is not connected, or a contact may be missing from your NMOS.